# SSL pinning getting success even on different certificate

Tags: android, ssl, public-key, certificate-pinning

I am trying to do certificate pinning. The network library my company used doesn't support pinning. So I have to do it manually.

This is the code I use

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    String actualKey = "OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=ccf0883ebc511bb86f7f6e360385cf3a" +
            "8720fa0d9f3367278baf2fd43d29c21b4384f09ae14207beeb429563639d4388aca65a3" +
            "a5f5d2c902bf33e6df904598e6a5a1c037add731bdce606c664368cbc4bb7e269bbda82" +
            "ff20bd9ca484f5bd660d5628bca4a8f376acf1cab07f0d9476df283ef44d3bf52d4b730" +
            "3187cf587cbb2ce981e01b6cb32ba4f9b197b60013ff19215abb7d2ca9608007df82641" +
            "b05127ec9557927e8bd68ff183f8b72720f93152f207f89b446e38fc7aa3db4928f5fb7" +
            "92f33898381e7bc5ddb612d2e3a3191854797add8e0d47ed9f7da709e55a89aa7369620" +
            "2d90275ada9d43fb462a16839787b6ea3c83df66a1d6e528a38d0d,publicExponent=1" +
            "0001}";

    try {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("prisonvoicemail.com", 443);
        socket.startHandshake();

        Certificate[] certs = socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
        Certificate cert = certs[0];
        String key = cert.getPublicKey().toString();

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, key);

        if(key.equals(actualKey)){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Success");
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Failure");
        }

    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. When I connect normally it get success, when I connect through a proxy (mitmproxy) to test a different certificate simulating a man in the middle attack, I also get success. It's like its completely bypassing the proxy and going straight to the normal certificiate. I don't know why this is.

Comment: Most likely your mitmproxy setup is wrong and you are *not* doing a man-in-the-middle. Using the toString() method of PublicKey is a poor way of comparing public keys. Instead you should use something like getEncoded().

Comment: @JamesKPolk I have tried to use getEncoded and converting it to base64. Mitmproxy is configured correctly because it works when using OKhttp. But the app was originally created by someone else an d so using Ion.  So having to write it is annoying.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I have tried to use `SSLSocket` and retrieve the certificate from the socket.